# Git Commit - How can I add current project version

Tags: git, maven, bitbucket, versioning

I wanted to add my current pom/project version in my bitbucket pipeline commit.

I've used the command:

```
git commit -m "[skip ci] New POM version - ${project.version}"
```

but it gives me the error "Bad substitution".

Is there a way to add the current pom/project version to the commit message?

Comment: I've tried retrieving with the command mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version
but without success. I get the error Unknown lifecycle phase ".version"

Comment: What about quoting `project.version` like that? `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression='project.version'` Aside fron that, you might want to add `-q -DforceStdout` to the command.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to print the commit message but it's not only the project version. It's the entire build log.  I've used `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -D expression=project.version`. Also, with forceStdout it prints nothing

Comment: I told you to add `-q`. This removes the typical verbose build log.

Comment: With `-q` it doesn't print anything

Comment: You should not put a space between `-D` and `expression`.